# Excel starts as a background process when called from a Linux machine. I need it as an app

Tags: linux, excel, vba, background

I have to start Excel (2010) from a Linux server using a batch file *(run_excel.bat)* that resides in a Windows server. The Unix command is *'ssh account@domain pathname\run_excel.bat'*. The *run_excel.bat* file has a single line, *"`start c:\...\excel.exe c:\pathname_of_program\this_excel.xlsm"`*. The Excel program is supposed to do some calculations and its VBA has to *msgbox* at one stage to ask **"Do you want to modify the data?"** The problem is that Excel starts but never asks the question because it remains as a background process, not as an app -- this can be seen by Task Manager. I have included, in **Workbooks_Open()**, the statement **Application.Visible = True**, but Excel remains in the background, is never visible, and it doesn't stop where it should.

However, if I start the *run_excel.bat* from the Windows server (either by double clicking or from the cmd line) the batch file indeed calls Excel and it opens as an app with no problem, stopping where it has to stop to ask the question, and interacting with the user.

Is there any way of force Excel to start as an app when called from the Linux machine? This Excel program has to run automatically until it prompts the user.

Comment: I'm not sure about Linux specifically, but can you open a visible instance of Excel in Linux with a batch file at all? (if not opening a specific `xlsm` file?)  If Excel isn't appearing at all, I don't think it has anything to do with VBA making it visible or not; it's the way that Excel is being opened.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how the Excel application is made invisible, it's possible that `Application.Visible = True` alone isn't enough to display your workbook (and your `MsgBox`).

Your solution could be as simple as:

```
ActiveWindow.Visible = True
```

---

### Show *all* Excel windows

In case the window in question isn't the *active* window, you can show them *all:*

```
Sub ShowAllExcelWindows()
    Dim ww As Window
    With Application
        .Visible = True
        For Each ww In .Windows
            ww.Visible = True
        Next ww
    End With
End Sub
```

---

### Further Troubleshooting

You can **confirm the state** of the Excel **Application** *and* each **Excel Window** with this:

```
Sub checkActiveWindow()
    With ActiveWindow
        Debug.Print "activeWindow:", ".Caption=", .Caption
        Debug.Print , ".Visible=", .Visible
        Debug.Print , ".View=", .View
        Debug.Print , ".WindowState=", .WindowState
    End With
End Sub
```

> **XlWindowState Enumeration**
>
> ```
>  WindowState = xlMaximized -4137  
>                xlMinimized -4140  
>                xlNormal    -4143
> ```

---

### Notes:

- in some cases when the `Application.Visible=False`, Excel might "think" that `ActiveWindow.Visible=True` though it obviously can't be.
- the `Window(`*`index`*`)` numbers change depending on which window was last active.  (`ActiveWindow` is always `Window(1)`.)
- don't confuse the `Window` object with the `Windows` object, which represents a collection of Excel `Window` objects.  Properties and methods for the `Windows` object affect all open Excel windows, such as `Windows.Arrange xlArrangeStyleTiled` which will "tile" all open Excel windows.
- neither the `Window` object *nor* the `Windows` object are related to the operating system of the same name, *Microsoft Windows*.    <sub><sup>Clear as mud? :-)</sup></sub>

---

### Check visibility of *all* Excel windows

A slightly longer procedure to return window information for all open Excel windows, as well as the Excel application itself:

```
Sub checkExcelWindows()

    With Excel.Application 'get application window info
        Debug.Print "Application", ".Caption=", .Caption
        Debug.Print , ".Visible=", .Visible
        Debug.Print , ".WindowState=", .WindowState
        Debug.Print , ".Windows.Count=", Application.Windows.Count
    End With

    Dim w: For w = 1 To Windows.Count 'loop through open windows
        With Excel.Application.Windows(w)
            Debug.Print vbLf & "Window(" & w & "):", ".Caption=", .Caption
            If ActiveWindow.Index = .Index Then Debug.Print , "This is currently ""ActiveWindow""."
            Debug.Print , ".Visible=", .Visible
            Debug.Print , ".View=", .View
            Debug.Print , ".WindowState=", Switch(.WindowState = xlMaximized, "Maximized", _
                .WindowState = xlMinimized, "Maximized", .WindowState = xlNormal, "Normal")
        End With
    Next w

End Sub
```

There may be [other properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/window-object-excel#properties) you'll want to add to the procedure, for troubleshooting purposes.

---

## More Information:

- MSDN : **[Window Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/window-object-excel) (Excel)** *(with list of methods/properties)*
- MSDN : **[Windows Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/windows-object-excel) (Excel)**
- MSDN : **[Application.Visible Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-visible-property-excel) (Excel)**
- MSDN : **[Window.Visible Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/window-visible-property-excel) (Excel)**

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, ashleedawg. All the applications--other than Excel--that I tried to start from the Linux server start as background processes. I also tried remote starting with "cmd" and "call" with no better results. I will try next the other options that you indicated from inside VBA to determine what's happening.